# SwiftUI sectioned list with large data set is sluggish

Tags: list, swiftui

I am trying to create a sections list of a large data set, 20,000 plus records, but this applies for even lower data sets of 5k records,

I have looked at
https://www.raywenderlich.com/27201015-dynamic-core-data-with-swiftui-tutorial-for-ios

and it works fine for a small data set of 20 records but once I add more data by editing this function to create more records

```
  private func addTestFriends() {
    let request = Friend.fetchRequest()
    let context = PersistenceManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
    do {
      if try context.count(for: request) == 0 {
        for number in 1...1000 {
          print(number)
          try Friend.generateTestFriends(in: context)
        }
      }
    } catch {
      print("Error generating friends: \(error)")
    }
  }
```

Which results in 20,000 records the app is really really sluggish, just closing the sections with the disclosure is slow.

Is this a flaw in SwiftUI or is there a different approach?

I also looked at Apples
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/loading_and_displaying_a_large_data_feed

which when doing a flat fetch of 10,000+ earth quakes loads fine, but once I try to section it

```
@SectionedFetchRequest(sectionIdentifier: \.code, sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.time, order: .reverse)], animation: .default)
private var quakes2: SectionedFetchResults<String, Quake>
```

sectioning it by "code" and it takes agessssss to load and then again is slugish

This seems a major flaw if you cannot create sections for large data sets of more that 1000 records

Comment: you are probably faulting 20,000 objects, you need to tune your fetch requests and have tighter SwiftUI View invalidation

Comment: ok any suggestions? I just used the examples by Ray and Apple and just added more data to the DB and used their fetch request,

Comment: so I need to fault the 20,000 objects or I should not fault them? how can I tune my fetch request, in my project I am using a sectionIdentifier, sorting by 2 sorts and then using a Predicate to get data matching my query. Tighter Swiftui View Invalidation? you mean try to reduce the causes to redraw the view, im my project I am simply changing a Bool to display a dropdown that causes a lag, or simply changing tabs to another tab

Comment: by tuning your fetch I mean configure it to fetch the properties `SectionedFetchResults` needs to do its job without firing faults on all the objects. Tighter Swiftui View Invalidation means make sub Views that take the object and access its properties in body so the fault is only fired when it appears.

Comment: Rays example already does the sub views ForEach(section) { friend in
              NavigationLink {
                AddFriendView(friendId: friend.objectID)
              } label: {
                FriendView(friend: friend)
              }
            } and I already do that on my production code, how do I fetch the properties inside the "SectionedFetchResults" ? Rays CoreData is very simple only 4 properties and no relationships so hard to see how that causes and issue, Would be good to find an example somewhere of code that can built sectioned lists from 1000s of entries that works

Comment: So I ran the demo app in Instruments CoreData and there are 0 faults so that cant be the issue and also it is using sub view to access properties so that's not the issue, So must be something else then or SwiftUI really is that bad, has anyone successful built a sectioned table with 20000+ records? and tell me how?

Comment: In instruments, Faults means a fault firing. So the fact you have 0 is the problem. Faults should fire as you scroll, if not then it means you have already fired the faults for the 20k records which is some serious memory usage.

Comment: I'm working on editing Earthquakes for more efficient core data, what field would you like to section on? Btw tailoring fetch requests is explained here https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10017/

Comment: Place would seem a good section to use, and awesome that would be great to see this and ill look at that link also

Comment: Yeh I tried place and I was experimenting with fr.propertiesToFetch = ["place", "time"] but sections still behaving very slow. Earthquakes is missing extension Quake : Identifiable and the ForEach needs changed to just quakes to work properly. Looks like the developer doesn't fully know SwiftUI.

Comment: thxs, makes it even harder for me to learn with examples like theirs, I've been trying fr.propertiesToFetch on my code but not sure how to use with the @Section wrapper so any code examples would be great, thxs

Comment: any more help on this from anyone?